# Python,como declarar una variable entre un max y un min?

Tags: python

Una pregunta si yo defino un maximo y un minimo usando If, como puedo definir el numero o variable que se encuentra en el medio?Muchisimas gracias!

```
Lado1=int(input("Ingrese lado:"))
Ingrese lado:3
>>> Lado2=int(input("Ingrese lado:"))
Ingrese lado:4
>>> Lado3=int(input("Ingrese lado:"))
Ingrese lado:5
>>> if Lado1>Lado2 and Lado1>lado3:
...     A=Lado1
... 
>>> if Lado2>Lado1 and Lado2>Lado3:
...     A=Lado2
... 
>>> if Lado3>Lado1 and Lado3>Lado2:
...     A=Lado3
... 
>>> A
5

if Lado1<Lado2 and Lado1<Lado3:
...     B=Lado1
... 
>>> if Lado2<Lado1 and Lado2<Lado3:
...     B=Lado2
... 
>>> if Lado3<Lado2 and Lado3<Lado1:
...     B=Lado3
... 
>>> B
3
```

Comment: requieres poner el ejemplo de lo que haz intentado y donde estas teniendo problemas, el sitio no funciona solo escribiendo lo que quieres y esperar a que alguien te lo resuelva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que lo que buscas es que ingresados tres valores obtener el máximo, el mínimo y el que queda entre ambos. Supongo que no puedes usar `list.sort`, `sorted`, etc:

```
lado_1 = int(input("Ingrese lado:"))
lado_2 = int(input("Ingrese lado:"))
lado_3 = int(input("Ingrese lado:"))

min, med, max = sorted((lado_1, lado_2, lado_3))

print("Valor máximo: {}\nValor medio: {}\nValor mínimo: {}".format(max, med, min))
```

Si solo puedes usar condicionales, existen varios algoritmos pero uno muy simple es el siguiente:

- De partida asignamos los tres valores a las variables `minimo`, `medio` y `máximo` tal y como se ingresan.
- Comprobamos si el valor mínimo es mayor que el medio, de ser así los intercambiamos.
- Comprobamos si el valor medio es mayor que el máximo, de ser sí los intercambiamos.
- En este punto tenemos ya el valor máximo. Solo nos queda volver a comprobar si el valor mínimo es mayor que el medio y de ser así los intercambiamos.

En realidad no hemos inventado nada nuevo, es ni más ni menos que el ordenamiento de burbuja (*bubble sort*) solo que simplificado a la mínima expresión. Sería simplemente:

```
lado_1 = int(input("Ingrese lado: "))
lado_2 = int(input("Ingrese lado: "))
lado_3 = int(input("Ingrese lado: "))

minimo, medio, maximo = lado_1, lado_2, lado_3

if minimo > medio:
    minimo, medio = medio, minimo

if medio > maximo:
    maximo, medio = medio, maximo

if minimo > medio:
    minimo, medio = medio, minimo

print("\nValor máximo: {}\nValor medio: {}\nValor mínimo: {}".format(maximo,
                                                                     medio,
                                                                     minimo))
```

> Ingrese lado: 15
>   Ingrese lado: -3
>   Ingrese lado: 45
>
> Valor máximo: 45
>   Valor medio: 15
>   Valor mínimo: -3

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar este código, es una adaptación a un código realizado en c++, **te ayudaría solo si quieres obtener el intermedio en caso de ser sólo 3 números**.

```
    Lado1=int(input("ingrese un numero\n"))
    Lado2=int(input("ingrese otro numero\n"))
    Lado3=int(input("ingrese un nuemero\n"))

if(Lado1>Lado2 && Lado1<Lado3 || Lado1<Lado2 && Lado1>Lado2 )
    print("El numero intermedio es " + str(Lado1))
else if(Lado2>Lado1 && Lado2<Lado3 || Lado2<Lado1 && Lado2>Lado3)
     print("El numero intermedio es " + str(Lado2))
else if(Lado3>Lado1 && Lado3<Lado2 || Lado3<a && Lado3>Lado2)
    print("El numero intermedio es " + str(Lado3))
else
     print("No existe número intermedio")
```

fuente http://diagramas-de-flujo.blogspot.com/2013/03/valor-intermedio-de-3-numeros-codigo-c.html

Answer (score 0):

Si quires sacar el valor intermedio entre 3 valores, una opción más rápida, sería convertir los 3 valores en una lista, ordenaros y que devuelva el del medio:

```
>>> lado1 = 6
>>> lado2 = 8
>>> lado3 = 3
>>> valores = sorted([lado1, lado2, lado3])
>>> valores[1]
6
```